# Nokogiri ccs text selector without children

Tags: css-selectors, nokogiri

I have the following html code of which I need to extract the €194,99 using a Nokogiri css selector and I cannot get what I need.

```
<p class="price price-offer price-len5">
  <span class="border">
    <span class="price-old">€219,99</span>
    €194,99     
  </span>
</p>
```

I've tried these selectors without luck:

```
product.css('.price span:not(.price span span)').text
product.css('.price:not(.price-old)').text
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thnx

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nokogiri, but the bottom queryselector should read `.price :not(.price-old)`, with a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
product.at('.price-old').next.text
```

or

```
product.at('.price .border').children[-1].text
```

Comment: Thanks I implemented the second one with succes

Comment: or `product.at('.price .border').children.last.text` :)